# K-mean across each axis of numpy array

Tags: numpy, k-means, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array **A with shape (N,M)**. I am looking to run K-mean (K=2) algorithm across each M axis and get the result C which is an **array with shape (K,M)**.

M can be a really large number. what is the fastest and most scalable way I can compute C in python?

Comment: What is `1-D K-mean (K=2) algorithm`?

Comment: Hey :) Updated the question. By 1-D K-means I meant K means algorithm for 1 dimensional data.

Comment: Seems like the shape `(M,)` implies `K=1`.

Comment: @senderle you are right. updated the question.